# Spark dataframe throws error while doing logic for date_add function

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting the below error

I am trying to add days to the current date , basically i want current_date + week_day(current_day)

```
 scala> df.withColumn(  "week_day",   date_add(current_date(), dayofweek(current_date()).cast(IntegerType)  )).show(10,false)
 <console>:51: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
   df.withColumn(  "week_day",   date_add(current_date(), dayofweek(current_date()).cast(IntegerType)  )).show(10,false)
```

I have added the import statement also , Please help why it is throwing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.withColumn("week_day",expr(s"date_add(${current_date()},${dayofweek(current_date()).cast(IntegerType)})"))`

should give you the desired output.

You are passing the column as the second argument(dayofweek(current_date()).cast(IntegerType)) to date_add,it should be integer type instead